# Will the antenna be detuned by the presence of the MHF3 plug in parallel?

Tags: rf, antenna, impedance-matching, high-frequency

This is a design question. Below is the layout of a project that involves some features, including an ESP32 circuit and its antenna:

[image]

[image]

The part of the schematic related to both images is:

[image]

**THE PROBLEM:** The connection between the MHF3 plug and the jumper J4 is around 10mm, and it stays just below the actual 2.4GHz antenna (Pro-ob 440).

Will the presence of this "long" track and the MHF3 plug detune the antenna or cause any serious problem related to this parallel configuration?

**EDIT:** The following picture was upgraded to contain the RF signal as much as possible aside the upper border:

[image]

Comment: Not an RF expert. But I would say yes, it will detune the antenna. However, you can compensate for that using C68, C69 and L2. Probably. I suppose you will need very accurate RF models of everything, or spend some time with a network analyzer.

Comment: @mkeith, you think it's gonna differ a lot from expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

UFL connectors when used for RF production tests are placed in series to the antenna PCB traces.

See here:

https://www.megiq.com/images/Content/MegiQ-Antenna-Diversity-UFL.jpg

---

The mere presence of a small metal object might slightly modify the radiation pattern.

The problem is not the de-tuning of the antenna.

The problem is the impedance Zstub that the stub shows to the RF signal coming from C68.

If Zstub is of the same order of the Z of the antenna then you have a problem because part of the RF energy may go into the stub and possibly reflected back.

To estimate Zstub you need to know:

```
1. PCB trace parameters: witdh, length, thickness

2. PCB parameters

3. How the stub is terminated. Open circuit?
```

Comment: that's a good point, and I don't know how to measure the stub interference, but for what you pointed I have some answers: 1- Everyt track on the antenna line is measured to be 50 Omhs (0.293 mm width). The stub is around 10.5mm long, not counting the 0402 0 Ohm resistor jumper; 2- in this configuration, the stub would be left open, but my intention is to use the mhf3 connector to measure the output or smd antenna parameters. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Usually those connectors are placed in series without stub. They are used during the tests. When you plug in the test coaxial probe, the RF signal goes to the tester.

Comment: Would be a problem populate everything except the jumper J4, so that the mhf3 connector is left disconnected?

Comment: That would be better. How long is the trace up to J4?

Comment: Both lines have around the same length of around 10.5mm

Comment: Don't populate J4 and do some tests. Afterwards, populate J4 and repeat the tests under the same conditions.

Comment: Sure, I'll be testing this when I receive the board! What about the via stiching, is it sufficient as it is now in my layout? I don't have much more space to place more gnd vias, due to the other layers underneath. (I don't have the option to use blind vias)

Comment: Your stiching vias parallel to antenna trace are fine. You should add stiching vias on the border with a step of 2.5/3 mm. You need them to contain within the PCB all RF spurious emissions that your RF transmitter inevitably radiates have when it sends more than 5 dBm to the antenna. Those are PA non linearities that you can't control using LC or harmonic filters because the exit from the IC.

Comment: It looks like J4 is right at the excitation point. So when J4 is removed, there is no stub on the transmission line. However, the antenna is directly above the trace from J4 to CONN1. If nothing else, the trace is creating a slot in the the top layer GND. This type of antenna usually works in conjuction with PCB GND to radiate. So not sure how it will work. Were you working from a reference design of some sort? Did it have instructions about GND near the antenna?

Comment: @EnricoMigliore, you say place via stiching though out all the border or its needed only for the closest border area near the antenna?

Comment: @mkeith, the antenna datasheet says: "The antenna is developed for optimum performance when mounted on a ground plane, and is therefore
very suitably mounted on a printed circuit board, where all empty space in the layout shall be filled solid
copper. This also means that no ground cutout area is required under the antenna." So it does not say it is required a GND plane underneath the antenna, but its a good practice. Said that, do you think I should remove the MHF3 connector?

Comment: After thinking about it, I don't think the trace leading to the MHF3 connector will be a big problem. You have good stitching to the GND plane on either side of the trace (there is a GND plane, right?). So the trace should not disrupt the "ground plane" effect too much. I think it will probably be OK. But of course you will have to validate the performance by testing and possibly tune passive values (L2, C68, C69).

Comment: Stiching vias is a standard practice for confining RF radiations inside a PCB. It's valid for PCBs with and without antennas. It's always valid. At CISCO they have a step of 2.5 mm. That means that they put a VIA on GND every 2.5 mm all around the border of the PCB.

Comment: @EnricoMigliore, good to know! It's not possible for me to add this lots of vias around the border, but I've edited the layout (as you can see on my upgraded post) in order to place as much vias as possible aside the border.

Comment: @mkeith, yes it's a GND plane allover the top layer, as my stack is composed by: top layer (GND/Signal), 2nd layer (GND), 3th layer (VCC/Signal), bottom layer (GND). The cost-limiting process of making a PCB lead me to use ONLY through-hole vias.